# I asked about all the jobs (not really)

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I'm currently seeing this message on **every** job posting:

> You asked about this job on Jul 2, 2015.

This applies to both jobs that I did ask about and jobs which I did not.

I did indeed **ask a question about a job on that date** (the job posting no longer exists) and notably its **the first "job question" listed under my Sent** folder, so maybe its selecting that date by accident?

Comment: What an inquisitive applicant! You must be quite the go-getter. You're hired.

Comment: Investigating now...

Comment: @kyle well if I could convert your comment to an answer I'd mark it as accepted! Let me go burn all the bridges at work and I'll report to you 1st thing tomorrow! Thank you for the opportunity! (struts into manager's office...)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We're using LINQ to SQL in this particular area of the code and a recent refactor on the data model caused it to generate a completely incorrect query. I've exchanged it for some actual SQL using Dapper and pushed the fix to production. Thanks for the report!

Comment: Guilty as charged. Thanks Dean

Comment: Looks good. It's now only showing up on "previously asked" jobs.  I guess this is the price you pay for Linq2SQL perf ;)

Comment: To be clear, it's showing the correct date on "questioned" posts as well. Thanx!